# Bootstrap Inline Form with Select Tag

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a inline form with bootstrap 3 that will have a text input, then a select tag, and a button. I've got it all inline however the width of each element is equal to the one besides it. I'm trying to achieve something similar to AirBnB's form. Do I need some custom css or does bootstrap have something built in that I'm not using?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search-text" placeholder="Search">
        </span>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <select class="form-control" name="args">
                <option>ex</option>
            </select>
        </span>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="submit" class="form-control"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
        </span>
    </div>  
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mnn4Lcqb/

Comment: how about [this](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/mnn4Lcqb/3/)

Comment: Well that pretty much answered it. I don't know why I didn't think of this before. Guess I just need to manually modify the width. Thanks a bunch @Raviteja

Comment: Thanks.Accept as an answer if it worked for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search-text" placeholder="Search">
    </span>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <select class="form-control" name="args">
        <option>ex</option>
        </select>
    </span>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button id="searchbtn" type="submit" class="form-control"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#searchbtn {
  width: 105px;
  background-color: #ff5a5f;
}
```

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/mnn4Lcqb/3/)